# Showing Two Labels of One feature In GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, sld

I have prepared a Web GIS Map using Geoserver-Openlayers_Postgis....For One Feature I need to show two labels such as "premise_no' & "bld_name'...
The following is the xml I used for styling(in geoserver)....
But it is showing either/or labels...

xml for layer styling(in geoserver)....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
    <sld:UserLayer>
        <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
        </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>v_building_ar</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title/>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>group 0</sld:Name>
                <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>generic:geometry</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>simple</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>1</sld:Name>
                    <sld:MinScaleDenominator>1.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
                    <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>2000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#FF8000</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.05</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>prem_no</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Label>
                        <sld:Font>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">8.0</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Font>
                        <sld:LabelPlacement>
                            <sld:PointPlacement>
                                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointY>0.0</sld:AnchorPointY>
                                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                                <sld:Displacement>
                                    <sld:DisplacementX>0.0</sld:DisplacementX>
                                    <sld:DisplacementY>0.0</sld:DisplacementY>
                                </sld:Displacement>
                            </sld:PointPlacement>
                        </sld:LabelPlacement>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:TextSymbolizer>
                  <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>bldname</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Label>
                        <sld:Font>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">8.0</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Font>
                        <sld:LabelPlacement>
                            <sld:PointPlacement>
                                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointY>0.0</sld:AnchorPointY>
                                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                                <sld:Displacement>
                                    <sld:DisplacementX>0.0</sld:DisplacementX>
                                    <sld:DisplacementY>0.5</sld:DisplacementY>
                                </sld:Displacement>
                            </sld:PointPlacement>
                        </sld:LabelPlacement>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:TextSymbolizer>                  
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The label placement algorithm will almost certainly decide not to show both labels as they will overlap. There are various vendor options that you can use to make it less picky about overlaps and clutter but it will end up looking ugly.

The better solution is to combine the two properties into one label (this will give you much more control over the way they line up etc. too). See the [user guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#composing-labels-from-multiple-attributes) for full details but try something like:

```
<sld:Label>
   <ogc:PropertyName>prem_no</ogc:PropertyName>, <ogc:PropertyName>bldname</ogc:PropertyName>
</sld:Label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides adding the two labels you can add autowarp option if you would like add the second label in the next line

```
<VendorOption name="autoWrap">50</VendorOption>
```

[image]

Comment: you would be better off using a new line instead of (or as well as) autowrap