# How to show Two Labels of One feature In Geoserver…? (Part 2)

Tags: geoserver, cartography, style, sld

This is how my SLD 1.0.0 rule looks like

```
  <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Title>Reser Type</sld:Title>
      <sld:PolygonSymbolizer/>
      <sld:TextSymbolizer>


        <sld:Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>fp_no</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:PropertyName>reser_use</ogc:PropertyName>
        </sld:Label>


        <sld:Font>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Font>
        <sld:LabelPlacement>
          <sld:PointPlacement>
            <sld:AnchorPoint>
              <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
              <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
            </sld:AnchorPoint>
          </sld:PointPlacement>
        </sld:LabelPlacement>
        <sld:Fill>
          <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#f42f08</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Fill>
      </sld:TextSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
```

My question is Is there any way we can display these 2 labels above and below and NOT in one line ?

Please refer [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/how-to-show-two-labels-of-one-feature-in-geoserver?rq=1) for more details.

Note 1: this is not a duplicate question read before reacting !!!!

Note 2: I tried \n it does not work

Comment: If you had read the answer to the previous question you would see it does answer your question too (read down the link provided).

Comment: <Label>
  <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[
]]>(<ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName>)
</Label>