# How to add a label based on multiple fields and brackets in GeoServer SLD

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

Is it possible to create a label which is comprised of multiple fields, in GeoServer using SLD?

For example, on the [Points](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#sld-cookbook-points) page of the SLD Cookbook, the *point with default label* section shows how to create a label based on the point attribute `name`:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
  <Label>
    <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
  </Label>
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
</TextSymbolizer>
```

How can I create a label based on two fields, which contains brackets around one of the fields? For example,

> name (population)
>
> Borfin (157860)

Testing shows that it's possible to add a new `<ogc:PropertyName>` element for the second attribute, and put the brackets on new lines:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
  <Label>
    <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
    (
    <ogc:PropertyName>pop</ogc:PropertyName>
    ) 
  </Label>
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
</TextSymbolizer>
```

but this results in a label containing a line break. How can I generate a label with all of the elements on a single line, as in `Borfin (157860)`?

Comment: Did you try using `<ogc:Literal>` to encase the brackets?

Comment: I have just tested 

     <Label>
        <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName> (<ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>)
     </Label>

     <Label>
        <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName> 
        (<ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>)
     </Label>

and both produce the correct label on one line.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a similar question with an answer

[How to show Two Labels of One feature In Geoserver....?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/how-to-show-two-labels-of-one-feature-in-geoserver)

You might need to modify the answer to insert the brackets.

Comment: How is what the OP asked different from the answer to the question you reference?

Comment: Thank you Mr KIA. Just answer constructively and leave unnecessary questions out.